# Pushing object to MongoDB array with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

Here is my mongo collection's sample:

```
{
   "data": {
      "categories": [
         {
            "categoryName":"Nature",
            "urls": [
               {
                  "name":"mountain",
                  "url":"mountain-url"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "categoryName":"Animals"
            "urls": [
               {
                  "name":"lion",
                  "url":"lion-url"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to push an object to urls array of Nature category.
I tried this:

```
collection.updateOne({"categories.$.categoryName":"Nature"},{$push:{"categories.$.urls":object}},(err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Successful');
  });
```

It returns 'Successful' but nothing change in MongoDB.
How can i do this ?

Comment: try removing $ from query part `{ "categories.categoryName": "Nature" }`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. @turivishal

Comment: try wrapping your query in async function and put await before query `await collection.updateOne`, if you have already used then please provide more debugging details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of my problem. Here is update code:

```
 collection.updateOne({"data.categories.categoryName":"Nature"},{$push:{"data.categories.$.urls":object}},(err, result) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Successful');
      });
```